# One VHD attached to multiple computers

Tags: windows-vista, vhd, virtual-disk

Is it possible to have one VHD and have multiple computers attach it? I get the error "Cannot attach vhd because another process is using it".

Comment: It is not possible.  Why would you want to do so in any case?